# I lost my 3 partition disk data in windows 10 after installing ubuntu 18.4

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

My laptop already i am installed windows 10 pro 64 bit version, i had 3 partitions in windows. 3 day before i am trying installing latest version of Ubuntu 18.4.0 64 bit.

that time i am never install alongside with windows os. i am trying new fresh installation. ( here i mistaken think fresh installing ubuntu only using my C: drive disk of windows ) but it deleted all my datas and deleted all my partitions. please help me the correct way of recovery data. Data for my 10 years collection.

Comment: If you did a fresh install **over** windows, then all your data is gone, this is why there is a warning telling you it will **erase the contents of the disk**. Or did you attempt to install alongside windows for a dual boot?

Comment: STOP using disk. If you used entire drive for Ubuntu, you erased all partitions. Ubuntu does randomly place files everywhere on drive, but new install is not large, so you may be able to recover some or most of your data. But if you use full drive encryption, the only recovery is from your backups. You can try testdisk & photorec, but some say Windows tools may be better for NTFS recovery. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step If that shows NTFS partition, see if deeper search finds files. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step only finds files by extension.